# Prisma how to add hours while comparing columns in the same table

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am using NestJS and Prisma[4.4.0].

My table:

```
id: int
created_at: Timestamp
first_active: Timestamp
```

Query that I want to implement

```
select count(*) from {table} where id = {id} and first_active <= {created_at} + 48hours
```

I want to get a count of users which were active within 48 hours of creation.

With https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#compare-columns-in-the-same-table now I can access the column name.

Example

```
where: {
// find all users where 'name' is in a list of tags
id: ${id},
first_active: {
  this.prisma.table.fields.created_at // Not sure how to + 48 hours
}
```

},

any suggestion on how I can add time (72 hours) to the `created_at`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform two queries to accomplish this, for now. First, retrieve the `created_at`, then add the necessary hours.

You could create a [feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=) if you would like to see this functionality added to Prisma.